# CakePHP Exception: Shell class for "..." could not be found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

The following is a snippet from my console, I baked a shell, and immediately try to use it, it should output getOptionParser, but it throws a MissingShell Exception instead, any ideas?

```
└──╼ bin/cake bake shell coin --plugin WalletManager
Welcome to CakePHP v3.4.7 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : src
Path: Projects/AltCoinWallet.Solutions/CakeCoin/src/
PHP : 5.6.30
---------------------------------------------------------------
Creating file plugins/WalletManager/src/Shell/CoinShell.php
Wrote `plugins/WalletManager/src/Shell/CoinShell.php`


└──╼ bin/cake coin
Exception: Shell class for "..." could not be found. 
in [...src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 327]
```

Answer (score 2):

You've baked a plugin shell, hence you need to refer to the plugin:

```
bin/cake wallet_manager.coin
```

or

```
bin/cake WalletManager.coin
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Shells, Tasks & Console Tools](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html)**

Comment: └──╼ bin/cake WalletManager.coin
Exception: Shell class for "WalletManager.Coin" could not be found. in [.../src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 327]

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts Please try both syntaxes, make sure that the plugin is being loaded in your bootstrap, and that the autoloader contains your plugin and is up to date.

Comment: turns out, it wasn't in the composer.json autoloader